# Can Microsoft Intune on macos track if the apps are being used in browser and find other unmanaged devices?

Tags: macos, browser, office365, intune, managed

We are working remotely and recently my company insisted everyone to install Intune company portal on the company provided laptops, turning them to managed devices (ownership type says ‘personal’).

1. Does this mean I can not check email or meetings from any other unmanaged device’s browser if the laptop dies or something? I’m wondering how Intune can manage the devices and track users if the office apps (email, calendar, onedrive and others) can be accessed from browser of any device? I always work in the browser of the company laptop instead of opening hundred apps. So I don’t see how managed device is going to make a difference.
2. Plus the management profile says it can query network data. Does that mean it can find all other personal devices on the same network and track them?

Comment: My apologizes I didn't notice you were using MacOS and focused on the fact your device was now being managed by Intune.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it's macbook that got managed by intune. So what are we expecting now? Can I still check my emails and other apps from a browser of any unmanaged device? Can the admins find my personal devices connected to the same home network? How do we set a clear wall between personal and work devices, so that neither can get accessed by the other one?

Comment: The only device that is managed is the one you enrolled.

Comment: I'd have installed it on a VM inside your Mac, not on the Mac itself. If the company doesn't own your Mac, they are actually exceeding their bounds by doing this. I would have serious words with IT.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, it’s provided by the company, but It was brand new back then and not corporate managed. Now it is. That’s fine but I’m just concerned that if I check my email and other office 365 apps from browsers of other personal devices, can they track those devices as well? Plus I don’t understand exactly what they can do on the Mac. Apple has some clue here https://www.apple.com/in/business/it/ but I don’t know about intune. Also I run it on my home’s guest network.

Comment: I don't know Intune specifically either, but the golden rule is 'don't do personal stuff on a company-managed computer'. That way there's nothing for them to find. At worst, set up another [private] admin account & don't share details between them.